# Flash games should I use MP3 or WAV file format?

Tags: flash, audio

I'm developping a flash game and I'm wondering what audio format is more suitable (MP3 or WAV)?

I understand that MP3 is much smaller but it has worst audio quality when is compared to WAV files.

Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: The audio quality difference between mp3 and wav formats is very minimal (for any sound you're going to use in a game).  Encoding rates and speaker quality are bigger factors than the format used in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Adobe's [Programming AS3](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part6_ProgAS_1.html) (Chapter Working with sound --> Basics of working with sound),

> Although there are various sound file formats used to encode digital audio, ActionScript 3.0, Flash Player and AIR support sound files that are stored in the mp3 format. They cannot directly load or play sound files in other formats like WAV or AIFF.

If you embed any other format in fla, then that will be converted to mp3 during publish.

Answer (score -1):

You should try OGG:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg
And also, WAV would be far too big. MP3 with 320 kbps should be sufficient.